# Connection String DI in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, I want to use the connection string from appsettings.json and use DI to setup my DbContext for use.

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DarkwinterDatabase": "server=localhost;userid=user;pwd=pass;port=3306;database=Darkwinter;sslmode=none;"
  },
  ...
}
```

In the ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs I have the following code.

```
services.AddDbContext<PostContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DarkwinterDatabase")));
```

My DbContext has one DbSet and accepts DbContextOptions to pass to base to be initialized. This is where I think I am wrong but should DI pass options to this class?

```
public class PostContext : DbContext
{
    public PostContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Post> Post { get; set; }
}
```

How ever when I try to use my Context I get an error: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'options' of 'PostContext.PostContext(DbContextOptions)

```
using(var db = new PostContext())
{
    var posts = db.Post.ToList();
    return View(posts);
}
```

This makes sense since I didn't pass one in but I thought that the service should do that? I know I am thinking about this the wrong way and was hoping someone would take the time to explain it to me.

Comment: What is the DI engine that you use? Where do you config your DI to know about an object of `DbContextOptions` type?

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking the right way. However, there are a couple of issues.

Let me explain: according to the [Dependency Injection documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) the `AddDbContext` is a registered extension method for .NET Core Dependency Injection, that is right.

What's more important is to understand what you are injecting. It's actually very easy: with `AddDbContext<PostContext>` you are telling the DI framework "*inject the PostContext as the application Db context everywhere where it's needed*".

Now let's check what you have in `PostContext` (that's where you want stuff injected **into**):

```
public PostContext(DbContextOptions options)
```

You are trying to use constructor injection, that's a great start. You are also expecting `DbContextOptions` to be injected. However, the DI framework has no idea what to inject for DbContextOptions - you only told it about `ApplicationDbContext` and it does not know which one to inject (*you might have registered a bazillion of different contexts*).

You can change it to `ApplicationDbContext` (otherwise everything written below makes zero sense):

```
AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(//...)
```

Now, your original DbContext service definition is done properly but it's still not working. There are good news for you though: you are not the only one who was *shockazzeled* by this behavior: "*I'm registering an ApplicationDbContext and then asking for DbContextOptions and I really expect for the magic to happen*" (ref. [Entity Framework Issue #4558](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4558)).

I have never actually tried this but according to the [Entity Framework Issue #4668](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4668) the `DbContextOptions<TContext>` was added to the application's service provider. Now, you probably already guessed the trick to try: make the constructor ask for `DbContextOptions<TContext>` (if you have changed your registration to use `ApplicationDbContext` instead of `PostContext`), like this:

```
public class PostContext : DbContext
{
    public PostContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Post> Post { get; set; }
}
```

Or like this if you have decided to stay with `AddDbContext<PostContext>`:

```
public class PostContext : DbContext
{
    public PostContext(DbContextOptions<PostContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Post> Post { get; set; }
}
```

Again, not sure if it will work, never tried it. If it doesn't - well, you'll have to implement a context options factory and inject it instead...

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me, but your answer was very insightful and I learned a lot. I am still playing around with the DI and trying different things but in the mean time I have hard coded my conn string to continue developing my blog. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this in your startup.cs file

```
services.AddDbContext<PostContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DarkwinterDatabase")));
```